# Overlay caption selection on parent hover

Tags: html, css

I'm working on on a caption for my gallery overlay, which would move onto the overlay on hover, changing it's `top` attribute, then on mouse out it would hide back below the thumbnail. So far I've tried this way, but I'm not sure how to select the `.gallery-caption` at `.gallery-item:hover` after I've specified some attributes separately at `.gallery-item:hover`. Is there some clever solution, or should I use jQuery instead?

```css
.gallery {
  margin-top:50px;
}
.gallery-item {
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid white;
  position:relative;
}
.gallery-overlay {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  transition:1s;
}
.gallery-overlay img {
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}
.gallery-overlay:hover {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  transition:1s;
}
.gallery-overlay:hover + .gallery-caption {
  top:-50px;
  transition:1s;
}
.gallery-caption {
  height:50px;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="gallery clearfix col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- new row starts -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500">
      </div>
      <p class="gallery-caption text-center">Item caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think in this case javascript will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define following code for your caption:

```
.gallery-caption{height:50px;
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
  transition:1s; 
  z-index:999}
```

And define following code for caption items:

```
.gallery-item:hover .gallery-caption{display:block; }
```

Comment: .gallery-overlay:hover {background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);transition:1s;
}
.gallery-overlay:hover .gallery-caption { display:block;} 
My problem is that after I've specified the .gallery-overlay:hover, the .gallery-overlay:hover .gallery-caption doesn't work.

Comment: add z-index:999 to your .gallery-caption, it will define top priority for showing an element

Comment: This way it works, yeah. But it just simply appears, I'd like to animate the way it slips up on mouse in and slips down on mouse out. But if I place it under the image as beginning position, it overlays the image below due to it's top z-index position.

Comment: if you want to have this feature which css can use from css animations like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations and https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check them out but it seems like the stuff I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this could be done with CSS but I would suggest a jQuery solution (on hover or similar. :)

Comment: On '.gallery-caption' hover how can I select the certain '.gallery-caption'? I'm thinking about something like $(this).$('.gallery-caption').animate, but this way isn't correct.

Comment: how about using :nth-child(x) ?  :)

Comment: Also assuming you want to use different images, you could check what the image source is equal to and then change the relevant caption based on that. :)